# How to overlay three separate figures over main figure in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a pcolormesh figure developed using the code below:[image]

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 y_values = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
 two_d_array = np.random.random((100,1000))

 plt.figure(figsize = (15, 7))
 plt.pcolormesh(two_d_array, cmap = 'seismic')
 plt.show()
```

I also have three functions that have the same y-axis but different x-axes.

```
 x_1 = y_values**2
 x_2 = y_values - 17 * y_values**2
 x_3 = y_values - 57

 plt.figure(figsize = (4, 7))
 plt.plot(x_1, y_values, color = 'k', linewidth = 4)
 plt.show()

 plt.figure(figsize = (4, 7))
 plt.plot(x_2, y_values, color = 'k', linewidth = 4)
 plt.show()

 plt.figure(figsize = (4, 7))
 plt.plot(x_3, y_values, color = 'k', linewidth = 4)
 plt.show()
```

[image]

How do I overlay each of the three function graphs over the original figure such that they share the same y-axis but maintain their original x-axes such that I get something like this without the white space present and evenly spread out. (Losing the original graphs x-axis tick labels is okay/good):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

```
y_values = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
two_d_array = np.random.random((100,1000))
x_1 = y_values**2
x_2 = y_values - 17 * y_values**2
x_3 = y_values - 57


fig, ax0 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))
ax0.pcolormesh(two_d_array, cmap = 'seismic')
ax0.set_axis_off()

gs0 = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1,3, subplot_spec=ax0)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[2])

for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3]:
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)

ax1.plot(x_1, y_values, color = 'k', linewidth = 4)
ax2.plot(x_2, y_values, color = 'k', linewidth = 4)
ax3.plot(x_3, y_values, color = 'k', linewidth = 4)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code that looks like it does what you want

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.signal import convolve2d

image = convolve2d(np.random.random((150, 250)), np.ones((50,5)), mode='same') 

f, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.imshow(image)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

lim = ax.get_position().get_points()
xmin, ymin = lim[0]
dx, dy = lim[1] - lim[0]

n = 3
ax2gap = 2 # ratio of the length of the subaxes to the length of the gap

total = n*(ax2gap+1)+1
d = dx/total
x0 = xmin + d
# or total = n*(ax2gap+1) ; d = dx/total ; x0 = xmin + d/2
# if you want less background on the sides

axes  = [f.add_axes((x0, ymin, d*ax2gap, dy))]
axes += [f.add_axes((x0+i*d*(ax2gap+1),
                    ymin,
                    d*ax2gap,
                    dy), sharey=axes[0]) for i in range(1, n)]

x = np.arange(51)/5
i = 5
for newax in axes:
    newax.plot(x,x*(10-x)/i)
    i = i+5

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can change the ratio between blanks and background modifying `ax2gap` and, of course, the number of subplots modifying `n`